# word2vec guesing word embeddings

Tags: word2vec

can word2vec be used for guessing words with just context?
having trained the model with a large data set e.g. Google news how can I use word2vec to predict a similar word with only context  e.g. with input ", who dominated chess for more than 15 years, will compete against nine top players in St Louis, Missouri."  The output should be Kasparov or maybe Carlsen.

I'ven seen only the similarity apis but I can't make sense how to use them for this?  is this not how word2vec was intented to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the intended use of word2vec. The word2vec algorithm internally tries to predict exact words, using surrounding words, as a roundabout way to learn useful vectors for those surrounding words.

But even so, it's not forming exact predictions during training. It's just looking at a single narrow training example – context words and target word – and performing a very simple comparison and internal nudge to make its conformance to that one example slightly better. Over time, that self-adjusts towards useful vectors – even if the predictions remain of wildly-varying quality.

Most word2vec libraries don't offer a direct interface for showing ranked predictions, given context words. The Python gensim library, for the last few versions (as of current version 2.2.0 in July 2017), has offered a `predict_output_word()` method that roughly shows what the model would predict, given context-words, for some training modes. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.predict_output_word

However, considering your fill-in-the-blank query (also called a 'cloze deletion' in related education or machine-learning contexts):

```
_____, who dominated chess for more than 15 years, will compete against nine top players in St Louis, Missouri
```

A vanilla word2vec model is unlikely to get that right. It has little sense of the relative importance of words (except when some words are more narrowly predictive of others). It has no sense of grammar/ordering, or or of the compositional-meaning of connected-phrases (like 'dominated chess' as opposed to the separate words 'dominated' and 'chess'). Even though words describing the same sorts of things are usually near each other, it doesn't know categories to be able to determine that the blank must be a 'person' and a 'chess player', and the fuzzy-similarities of word2vec don't guarantee words-of-a-class will necessarily all be nearer-each-other than other words.

There has been a bunch of work to train word/concept vectors (aka 'dense embeddings') to be better at helping at such question-answering tasks. A random example might be ["Creating Causal Embeddings for Question Answering with Minimal Supervision"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08097) but queries like [word2vec question answering] or [embeddings for question answering] will find lots more. I don't know of easy out-of-the-box libraries for doing this, with or without a core of word2vec, though.